# Why I cannot load JavaScript-script using normal working URL?

Tags: javascript, html

When I put this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.citygridmedia.com/ads/scripts/v2/loader.js"></script>
```

to my html-file (inside or outside `<head></head>`), and I get failed-GET request.
(same experience in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6fznd/)

[image]

However,  if I open this link directly on browser, everything looks normal (e.i. I see the script when I open this link: http://static.citygridmedia.com/ads/scripts/v2/loader.js).

Why I cannot load this script on html page?

Comment: That works for me.  Try Ctrl+F5

Comment: Works for me. Over aggressive Ad-blocker possibly?

Comment: @Alohci, yes, you are right, it was ad-blocker. Thanks for feedbacks, it'd take an eternity to find the reason by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is loading fine, even in jsFiddle. Maybe you're facing some weird problem with your internet.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Where are you compiling this code. If your using something like coda, you may have an issue with running javascript hosted externally for security reasons. There could also be an issue with your javascript. I would use jquery for get requests.